# Neo4j Server: How to set connection timeouts

Tags: neo4j, embedded-jetty

How do set - in my case raise - the connection timeouts of the Neo4j server? I have a server extension to which I POST data, sometimes that much that the extension is running for a couple of minutes. But after 200 seconds, the connection is dropped by the server. I think I have to raise the max idle time of the embedded jetty - but I don't know how to do that since it's all configured within the Neo4j Server code.

Edit: I've tried both Neo4j 1.8.2 and 1.9.RC2 with the same result.

Edit2: Added the "embedded-jetty" tag because there are no answers until now; perhaps the question can be answered by someone with knowledge about embedded Jetty since Neo4j uses an embedded Jetty.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

The server guards against orphaned transactions by using a timeout. If there are no requests for a given transaction within the timeout period, the server will roll it back. You can configure the timeout period by setting the following property to the number of seconds before timeout. The default timeout is 60 seconds.

org.neo4j.server.transaction.timeout=60

See http://docs.neo4j.org/chunked/stable/server-configuration.html

Comment: Thank you for your answer. However, as I wrote above this is not my problem. I don't get a timeout message and a rollback after 60 seconds but a lower-level connection timeout after 200 seconds and NO rollback since I use my own server extension. Back when the problem came up, I also tried the option you mentioned by setting it to a high value, with no success. The problem here is a default idle connection timeout by the Jetty used in Neo4j up to 1.9.x. There is a Neo4j issue for this here: https://github.com/neo4j/neo4j/issues/882

Answer (score 1):

I still don't know if there is a solution in the Neo4j server with versions <2.0. However, with switching to 2.0.0 and above, this issue was gone for my case.